# Using ACCEPT within a BEGIN block in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use ACCEPT in my BEGIN block but I keep getting errors.  I want to accept user input if the if condition is fired.  How can I fix this?  Below is my script:

```
ACCEPT ExpNum NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter an expense number:  ';

SELECT *
FROM ExpByCC
WHERE ExpNum = &ExpNum;

SELECT IsCash,CashAmt
FROM EXPMAST
WHERE ExpNum = &ExpNum
AND IsCash = 'Y';

ACCEPT CashAmount PROMPT 'Enter the amount of cash used for the expense:  ';

DECLARE
    CashTotal NUMBER(11,2);

BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(Amt)
    INTO CashTotal
    FROM EXPDET
    WHERE ExpNum = &ExpNum;

    IF &CashAmount < (CashTotal - 0)
    THEN
            ACCEPT CType PROMPT 'Enter a credit card type:  ';
            ACCEPT CCNum PROMPT 'Enter a credot card number:  ';
            ACCEPT Amt Prompt 'Enter an amount:  ';


    END IF;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

`ACCEPT` is a SQL*Plus command.  It is interpreted by the client (SQL*Plus) before code is sent to the database.  PL/SQL is a language that runs exclusively on the server.  You cannot, therefore, intertwine the two.  You cannot embed SQL*Plus commands inside a PL/SQL block.  As a general rule, PL/SQL blocks cannot interact with users.

If you want to get really, really down in the weeds, it would possible to build a rather complicated bit of branching logic into your SQL*Plus script so that a second script with only the three `ACCEPT` statements would be run if and only if `&CashAmount < (CashTotal - 0)` but that is rarely an appropriate approach.  That would probably involve creating a new SQL*Plus variable called, say, `next_script`, populating that variable as part of your block, and then dynamically calling `next_script` in your script.  That is not a way, however, to build solid, reliable, easy to maintain systems.